# How do I query records from my database in PHP so it appears on the URL

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
//Create connection credentials
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';

//Create mysqli object
$mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name); 

//Error Handler 
if($mysqli->connect_error){
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}

<?php
//Set question number
$number = (int) $_GET['n'];

/*
*   Get Question
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`
            WHERE question_number = $number";
//Get result
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$question = $result->fetch_assoc();             
?>
```

I have made a database in phpMyAdmin and am trying to query the questions I have created. 
I have used this code and when I save and refresh this in the web browser it replies "No database selected12".
I have created the sql connection to the database that is all fine its just when I try to query the questions to appear on the web page it doesn't work.
the first half of the code was created in database.php file then just used in another.
Please can someone help me!!! Thanks

Comment: Your browser is saying you haven't, you're saying you have. So where have you *created the sql connection to the database*?

Comment: post your full php script, it seems you init your connection after you process your GET

Comment: these comments aren't easy for anyone to interpret - update your question with all the relevant code & filenames & you'll probably get the answer you need.

Comment: all has been updated

Comment: Why do you include `database.php` AND connect to the database on the same page?

Comment: I could do just had them on different pages and copied the code to look like it was one file but both on different files